# Typescript types for unsubscribe from firestore and Redux-Thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a Thunk Action that looks like:

```
export const doTestCall = (teamId:string): ThunkAction<()=>void, RootState, null, MoodAction> => {
    return dispatch => {
      const unsubscribe = db.doc("id").onSnapshot(doc =>{
        //whatever
      });
      return unsubscribe;
    }
  }
```

In my react component I have the following hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = dispatch(doSomething()) as ()=>void;
        return () => unsubscribe();
}, []);
```

This code actually works.
Question I have, how can I remove forcing the

```
as ()=>void
```

If I do, code complains in the "return line" with:

```
const unsubscribe: (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<RootState, null, MoodAction>, getState: () => RootState, extraArgument: null) => void
Expected 3 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
index.d.ts(9, 3): An argument for 'dispatch' was not provided.
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `ThunkAction<()=>void, RootState, null, MoodAction>` does not match the definition of your middleware.

I would assume that something like

```
ThunkAction<()=>void, RootState, unknown, AnyAction>
//or
ThunkAction<()=>void, RootState, any, AnyAction>
```

would work better, assuming your `dispatch` typings include the types for the thunk middleware at all.

If you are using the officially recommended redux toolkit, setting up the correct `dispatch` type is documented here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript